# some windows form controls not recognized?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a a couple of ordinary Windows Forms. To clear the data entry fields in one of them I use code something like this:

```
    ClearInputFields(this);

    private void ClearInputFields(Control Page)
    {
        try
        {
            foreach (Control ctrl in Page.Controls)
            {
                if (ctrl is Button)                    
                    continue;
                if (ctrl is DataGridView)
                    continue;
                if (ctrl is ListBox)
                    continue;

                if (ctrl is TextBox)
                {
                    ((TextBox)(ctrl)).Text = string.Empty;
                }
                else if (ctrl is ComboBox)
                {        
                    ((ComboBox)(ctrl)).SelectedIndex = 0;
                }
                else if (ctrl is CheckBox)
                {
                    ((CheckBox)(ctrl)).Checked = false;
                }
                else if (ctrl.Controls.Count > 0)
                {
                    ClearInputFields(ctrl);
                }                                       
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            TraceFile.Error("ExceptionLog", ex);
        }
    }
```

On one of the forms it works as expected. On the other form two out of nine ComboBoxs are NOT reset, and none of the six CheckBoxes are cleared.

Stepping through in the debugger, it appears that the particular controls are not even in the list of controls contained in the form.?!

I have compared the forms, and see nothing different in the properties of these controls. One of the comboBoxes that is not recognized is databound, one is not, but this is also true in the case of those that are reset.

I have looked at the designer, and all controls are declared as "this.Controls.Add(this.name_of_control);"

I have tried leaving out the last "else if" (there are no panels, group boxes, or other containers on this form anyway). No difference in behavior.

If I explicitly set the Checkboxes to "Checked = false", and set the ComboBoxes to "SelectedIndex = 0" they do what I expect, but not when iterating through the controls of the form.

EDIT - Addendum: All controls are created in the Designer, not at runtime. As mentioned, there are no containers on the form.

I expect this is one of those simple, obvious, right under your nose issues, but so far I'm not seeing it.

Any insights appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Are you creating any control in the runtime ? Compare _Page.Controls.Count_

Comment: Are your other controls inside containing controls?  You may have to have logic that looks for the containing control then reexecutes passing it's container.

Comment: @SASS_Shooter The code is already doing that.  It's recursive.

Comment: This code will fire event handlers.  If you do anything with the Z-order of the controls in event handlers then you'll have this problem.  And watch out for exceptions.

Comment: Aha! I am using the event handlers in some cases, but not in any intentional or known way altering the Z order of anything. However, this does give me a hint about altering my approach.

Comment: I tried separating out each control type into its own foreach loop, identifying and operating on only a single control type at at time. - I have seen cases where operations that "ought to have been" ok inside a loop turned out not to be. However, this did not change the behavior in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps when changing a control's property – the order of the controls in `this.Controls` changes, so you're not going through all controls. Although maybe this is not the case because maybe the `Control ctrl in Page.Controls` is checked only the first time.

Comment: That the order of the controls is changed when setting a property of one of them would certainly explain the behavior, which is why I did try separate loops (although this might not guarantee that the order was not changed). And other than "dumb luck", that doesn't explain why it works on the other form. And of course the logical end-point of this logic is that you *must* set each control individually.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever I have to do something on the items of a Collection that could alter it, I usually copy the collection and then loop through this copy. In your case this is the code that I usually write:

```
ClearInputFields(this);

private List<Control> ControlsForPage(Control Page)
{
        List<Control> result = new List<Control>();
        foreach (Control ctrl in Page.Controls)
              result.Add(ctrl);
        return result;
{

private void ClearInputFields(Control Page)
{
    try
    {
        List<Control> ctrlsCopy = ControlsForPage(Page);
        foreach (Control ctrl in ctrlsCopy)
        {
            if (ctrl is Button)                    
                continue;
            if (ctrl is DataGridView)
                continue;
            if (ctrl is ListBox)
                continue;

            if (ctrl is TextBox)
            {
                ((TextBox)(ctrl)).Text = string.Empty;
            }
            else if (ctrl is ComboBox)
            {        
                ((ComboBox)(ctrl)).SelectedIndex = 0;
            }
            else if (ctrl is CheckBox)
            {
                ((CheckBox)(ctrl)).Checked = false;
            }
            else if (ctrl.Controls.Count > 0)
            {
                ClearInputFields(ctrl);
            }                                       
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        TraceFile.Error("ExceptionLog", ex);
    }
}
```

Anyway, just to understand what's going on here, I would try to make the copy of Controls before doing your reset, and then compare it with the Controls collection of your page after the reset.

Comment: I hope what I'm doing to each item does not actually alter the collection, but it's a good suggestion. I will try this when I get back to work on Monday. Thanks!

Comment: This did not have any effect, and thinking about it, I'm not sure why it would - unless I'm missing something.. If I am making an actual copy of each control, I will be clearing my copies, not the controls on the form. If I am copying references to each control, this should behave as if I am simply operating on the original controls (which is what it does).

Comment: I didn' think that the collection would change, just the order